# R: how to group by nested intervals?

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe which looks like the following:

```
      d   b c  a
1  3400 100 3 -1
2  3400  50 3  1
3  3400 100 1 -1
4  3408  50 1  1
5  3412 100 3  1
6  3423  50 1  1
7  3434 100 1  1
8  3436 100 3  1
9  3438  50 3  1
10 3445  50 1  1
11 3454 100 3  1
12 3465 100 1  1
```

and I want to group by column a and b based on the condition that the group starts with column c value= 3 and the group ends if the column d value is + 30 ahead of the first group entry(So the interval length = 30, but the starting point of every interval can be in another interval). Then I want to count the rows in each group.

So the expected output for this sample should be:

```
b    a   rowcount 
100 -1    2        ( starting at d = 3400)
50   1    3        ( starting at d = 3400)
100  1    3        (starting at d= 3412)
50   1    2        (starting at d= 3438)
100  1    2        (starting at d= 3454)
```

I tried:

```
df<-df%>%
  group_by(b,a,first(c) == 3  & lead(d) - d < 30)
summarise(number = n())
```

but this does not give me the desired output. Any comments are appreciated!

UPDATE: New Example:

```
      d   b c a
1  3400 100 3 1
2  3400 100 3 1
3  3400 100 1 1
4  3408 100 1 1
5  3412 100 3 1
6  3434 100 3 1
7  3436 100 1 1
8  3438 100 3 1
9  3445 100 1 1
10 3443 100 3 1
11 3444 100 1 1
12 3463 100 3 1
13 3463 100 1 1
14 3463 100 3 1
```

Your code gives as output:

```
      a     b count desc                    addition_info                    
  <dbl> <dbl> <int> <chr>                   <chr>                            
1     1   100     5 ( starting at d = 3400) There is 3 `c == 3` in this group
2     1   100     6 ( starting at d = 3434) There is 3 `c == 3` in this group
3     1   100     3 ( starting at d = 3463) There is 2 `c == 3` in this group
```

but the third group is wrong, since the difference in d = 29 and therefore <30. Why is this the case? So the right output in this example should be:

```
      a     b count desc                    addition_info                    
  <dbl> <dbl> <int> <chr>                   <chr>                            
1     1   100     5 ( starting at d = 3400) There is 3 `c == 3` in this group
2     1   100     9 ( starting at d = 3434) There is 3 `c == 3` in this group
```

Comment: Starting from row 1, c == 3 so I start a group. Looking at additional rows with the same b (100) but d < 3400 + 30 = 3430, I see row 3 and 5 also fit the bill. So why is the first rowcount only 2? Does the c == 3 overrule the "within 30" d?

Comment: because column a == -1 for the first two b(100) rows (row 1 and 3)  and row 5 has for column a ==1, so this would start a new group

Comment: For the last one where `a =1; b = 100`, and `starting at d = 3454` the 2nd records has `d = 3645` so the d difference is more than `30` and still in same group?

Comment: I am sorry this was a mistake from my side, I corrected it. Thank you for your solution, is there a possibility to include the d<30 rule?

Comment: If a record (or a few) with `c == 1` and `d > 30` then what will happen. Would it (or they) be it own group or it will included in the next `c == 3`? What will happen to those `c != 3` after

Comment: They will be in the next group, which starts with a   c==3 . Every  c==3 column has a corresponding c==1  column, so there is no possibility for a group to have rowcount == 1.

Comment: DId that answer your question?

Comment: I updated the answer please check and see if this answer your quest ;)

Comment: Your code works but for some strange reason not always. I gave a new example where it does not work, do you have an idea why?

Comment: What if there is a 15th row in your second example say, 3470, 100, 1, 1? Please clarify? Will new group start as distance>30 but c is not 3?

Comment: Actually you are passing two simultaneous conditions for a group start/end.  What if end condition is satisfied and starting not satisfied? Will those rows have to be eliminated?

Comment: Thank you your solution works perfect!! regarding your question: my real dataset, contains of pairs of column c==3 and c==1, where 3 is always the first and the difference within the pairs is <0.01. So it is very unlikely, that a case like in your example occurs and i am willing to accept the risk, that this may happen in a rare case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tweaked your example a bit, still I think this will suffice largely.  (Also see notes below the code)

```
df <- read.table(text = "     d   b c a
1  3400 100 3 1
2  3400 100 3 1
3  3400 100 1 1
4  3408 100 1 1
5  3412 100 3 1
6  3434 100 3 1
7  3436 100 1 1
8  3438 100 3 1
9  3445 100 1 1
10 3443 100 3 1
11 3444 100 1 1
12 3463 100 3 1
13 3463 100 1 1
14 3463 100 3 1
15 3465 100 3 1", header = T)

#added one row in df
> df
      d   b c a
1  3400 100 3 1
2  3400 100 3 1
3  3400 100 1 1
4  3408 100 1 1
5  3412 100 3 1
6  3434 100 3 1
7  3436 100 1 1
8  3438 100 3 1
9  3445 100 1 1
10 3443 100 3 1
11 3444 100 1 1
12 3463 100 3 1
13 3463 100 1 1
14 3463 100 3 1
15 3465 100 3 1
```

Now follow this strategy

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table) # for rleid()


df %>% mutate(r = row_number()) %>%
  group_by(b, a) %>% mutate(grp_no = rleid(accumulate(d, ~ifelse(.y - .x > 30, .y, .x)))) %>%
  group_by(b, a, grp_no) %>%
  summarise(row_count = n(), r = first(r), d = first(d)) %>%
  arrange(r) %>%
  mutate(additional = paste("group starts at d =", d)) %>%
  select(-r, -d)

# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   b, a [1]
      b     a grp_no row_count additional              
  <int> <int>  <int>     <int> <chr>                   
1   100     1      1         5 group starts at d = 3400
2   100     1      2         9 group starts at d = 3434
3   100     1      3         1 group starts at d = 3465
```

With first example, its output is

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
# Groups:   b, a [3]
      b     a grp_no row_count additional              
  <int> <int>  <int>     <int> <chr>                   
1   100    -1      1         2 group starts at d = 3400
2    50     1      1         3 group starts at d = 3400
3   100     1      1         3 group starts at d = 3412
4    50     1      2         2 group starts at d = 3438
5   100     1      2         2 group starts at d = 3454
```

Note: you may also use `dplyr::dense_rank` instead of `rleid` in above syntax, like this

```
df %>% mutate(r = row_number()) %>%
  group_by(b, a) %>% 
  mutate(grp_no = dense_rank(accumulate(d, ~ifelse(.y - .x > 30, .y, .x)) )) %>%
  group_by(b, a, grp_no) %>%
  summarise(row_count = n(), r = first(r), d = first(d)) %>%
  arrange(r) %>%
  mutate(additional = paste("group starts at d =", d)) %>%
  select(-r, -d)
```

**EndNote: Now I am not how your logic of `c==3` fits into this?  If you'll clarify I may try again**

Comment: one question: how can i get the first and the last d entry? I tried it with dlast= last(d) in the summarise argument, but i got the same d value as with first()

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(purrr)
options(scipen = 999)
data <- structure(list(d = c(3400L, 3400L, 3400L, 3408L, 3412L, 3423L, 
  3434L, 3436L, 3438L, 3445L, 3454L, 3645L), b = c(100L, 50L, 100L, 
    50L, 100L, 50L, 100L, 100L, 50L, 50L, 100L, 100L), c = c(3L, 
      3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L), a = c(-1L, 1L, -1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")



# split data into group of a,b
new_data <- data %>% 
  group_by(a, b) %>%
  group_split()

# function group index - assuming that every c == 1 have a c == 3 before it
# then only need to sort by the d different with first record by less than 30
group_function <- function(df) {
  bin <- seq(from = min(df$d), to = max(df$d) + 30, by = 30)
  df <- df %>%
    mutate(d_group = cut(d, breaks = bin,
                         include.lowest = TRUE, right = FALSE)) %>%
    group_by(d_group)
  df$group_index <- group_indices(df)
  df %>% 
    group_by(a, b, group_index) %>%
    summarize(count = n(),
      desc = sprintf("( starting at d = %s)", first(d)),
      # I added the count of c==3 in the group just to show that sample data
      # is not follow the logic you mentioned
      addition_info = paste0("There is ",
                             sum(c == 3), " `c == 3` in this group"),
      .groups = "drop") %>%
    select(-group_index)
}
```

```
new_data %>%
  map_dfr(group_function)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>       a     b count desc                    addition_info                     
#>   <int> <int> <int> <chr>                   <chr>                             
#> 1    -1   100     2 ( starting at d = 3400) There is 1 `c == 3`` in this group
#> 2     1    50     3 ( starting at d = 3400) There is 1 `c == 3`` in this group
#> 3     1    50     2 ( starting at d = 3438) There is 1 `c == 3`` in this group
#> 4     1   100     3 ( starting at d = 3412) There is 2 `c == 3`` in this group
#> 5     1   100     1 ( starting at d = 3454) There is 1 `c == 3`` in this group
#> 6     1   100     1 ( starting at d = 3645) There is 0 `c == 3`` in this group
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

**Update: included the logics described.**